# mbstring extension installed but not working

Tags: php, apache, mbstring

I am using Linux Mint and apache2 with php5.6.

After installing everything it shows me that mbstring is required. After doing `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml`
 it shows me that I have the newest version already.

I also changed `;extension=php_mbstring.dll` to `extension=php_mbstring.dll` in `/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`

I did `sudo service apache2 restart`

Could anyone help me on this please?

EDIT:

php.ini file - http://pastebin.com/1U3UtHXn

Comment: Did you restart the apache service after you did the changes in the `php.ini`?

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: @darryn.ten `apt-get` means it's linux :)

Comment: apt-get on windows?

Comment: Its linux and yes I restarted apache.

Comment: well there's your issue, .dlls are for windows, and .so are for linux

Comment: @Dekel .dll means it's windows

Comment: Try run `sudo phpenmod mbstring`

Comment: @divHelper11 did you check my last comment?

Comment: @Dekel Yes, but unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: Did you check the error log?

Comment: @Dekel `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mbstring.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: And this file exists? `ls -l /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mbstring.so`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load a `.dll` file on Linux. Those are for Windows.

You need to load the equivalent `.so` file for Linux.

`apachectl configtest --verbose` should also help you here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well it always is trying to load the dll. Maybe because I enabled it in php.ini. Anyway: `Action 'configtest --verbose' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.` - nothing shows in apache log

Comment: You need to load the `.so` extension. That section should be below the `.dll` section. re-comment out the `.dll`

Comment: I added there `extension=php_mbstring.so` instead of dll but it still ask for dll everywhere. What the hell >.>

Comment: paste your php.ini on pastebin or something and link to it in your question

Comment: remove the `.so` you added on line 899 and try using phpenmod on the command line

Comment: It is still trying to load `/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mbstring.dll` after restarting apache

Comment: ye you're not going to get anywhere with that I have no idea how you ended up in that position. try phpenmod.

Comment: I will try to purge and install once again

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I actually did was deleting everything: php, php extensions, phpmyadmin, sql, everything and installing once again the most recent versions.